# syslog-ng hungup using afmongo

Tags: mongodb, syslog-ng

i'm using syslog-ng to send data to mongo
after a while the process hung up. tcpdump shows no data outgoing.
debuggint syslog-ng, i found Destination queue full, dropping message;... appears several times, then back to normal. for last time it never come back.
using kill -1 $PID can solve it. but the reason is unkown, i'm trying to figure it out.
if anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things which can cause this, but it's hard to tell without more information, I'd suggest asking on the syslog-ng mailing list too, as it's very likely I'd ask for a bit of debugging info there, which isn't all that suitable on stackoverflow.

Nevertheless, there's one known case of deadlock that I know of in afmongodb, which isn't fixed in 3.3.4, for that, there's a fix [available here](https://github.com/algernon/syslog-ng/commit/6bbb6786aee3120ca19b4f268672b407b0e6f213). From your description, I'm not sure this would help (the destination queue full stuff is interesting, by the way), but from what you describe, this is my best bet.

Hope it helps!